# Prove that $+$ is associative where $A+B=( A \setminus B )\cup( B \setminus A ) $.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then $A+B=( A \setminus B )\cup( B \setminus A ) $.
>
> Prove that $+$ is an associative operation.

How do I prove these?

Comment: What is $U$?...

Comment: Is $+$ the symmetric difference?

Comment: @Kaster , it's edited now , U meant union

Comment: By the way, the symmetric difference is usually written $\oplus$, the TeX for which is `\oplus`.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I've never seen $\oplus$ for symmetric difference. Only $\triangle$ and $\ominus$.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I think in this question it's meant that one defines some operation "$+$" by basic set operations and then one has to prove that it's associative. And BTW, it's not $\oplus$.

Comment: @Kaster Yes, that is obvious. My comment was to inform OP of an alternative notation for the operation.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber I get it, I and kahen are just saying that alternative notation you provided is not for symmetric difference.

Comment: And I have seen all three of these symbols used in the literature for symmetric difference: $\oplus, \ominus,$ and $\Delta$.

Comment: What can I say?  I have seen $\oplus$, usually in group theory.  It comes from the XOR usage.  I don't object to $\ominus$ or $\bigtriangleup$.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber what you're referring, I believe, is [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or)

Comment: See [Symmetric Difference is Associative](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_Difference_is_Associative) at ProofWiki and
[Another proof of $A \triangle (B \triangle C)=(A \triangle B) \triangle C$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129063/another-proof-of-a-triangle-b-triangle-c-a-triangle-b-triangle-c).
Somewhat related also: [Symmetric Difference Identity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52801/symmetric-difference-identity/)
and [Symmetric Difference with Intersection forms Ring](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_Difference_with_Intersection_forms_Ring) at ProofWiki.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to first prove that $x \in A+B$ is equivalent to "x belongs to exactly one of the sets $A$ and $B$".

You can then deduce that $x \in (A+B)+C$ and $x \in A+(B+C)$ are both equivalent to the statement "$x$ belongs to either exactly one or all three of the sets $A, B, C$".

I will leave you to work out the details, but let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: thanx ! this approach is Great ! i completed the details 

but is there other approach using the laws of set theory ? 

what is the laws which will be used in a proof like this ?

Comment: It is possible (but very messy, I think) to prove the result using the fact that $A \setminus B = A \cap B'$ (where $B'$ is the complement of $B$) and then doing a lot of set algebra. Another approach uses [indicator functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) and some simple algabra.

Comment: @CтарыйДжон Damn, I was looking to different Venn diagram all this time. Apologies for trying to start fruitless discussion. I removed all my posts to save myself from future embarrassment. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** The characteristic function of the set $A\subset X$ is defined by
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
  1_A: & X \rightarrow& \{0,1\} \\
   & x\mapsto & \left\{
           \begin{array}{ll}
             1 & \hbox{if}\, x\in A \\
             0 & \hbox{if}\, x\notin A
           \end{array}
         \right.
\end{array}$$
then it's easy to prove that 
$$1_{A\cap B}=1_A 1_B\quad;\quad 1_{A^c}=1-1_A\quad;\quad1_A=1_B\iff A=B$$
now it's easy to show that 
$$ A+(B+C)=(A+B)+C$$

Comment: is ther any law for $1_ {(A∪B)}$ ?

Comment: is the relation , $$
\textbf{1}_{B} + \textbf{1}_{C} = \textbf{1}_{B \Delta C}
$$ true ? where ${B \Delta C}$
 is the symmetric diffrence

Comment: @MrWhy If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subset then $1_{A\cup B}=1_A+1_B$, and since $B\Delta C=(B\cap C^c)\cup (C\cap B^c)$ then apply the relations given in my answer an you find $1_{B\Delta C}=1_B+1_C-21_B1_C$.

Comment: according to wikipedia , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function
, $1_{A∪B} $ = $ 1_{A} $ + $1_{B}$ - $ ( 1_{A} 1_{B} ) $ not 

 $1_{A∪B} $ = $ 1_{A} $ + $1_{B}$

Comment: @MrWhy This is true in general case but in case of disjoint subsets we have $1_{A\cup B}=1_A+1_B$ as I said.

Comment: ok :) thanks :))